# UWP Unzip a 7Z File

Tags: uwp, 7zip

I must to extract a 7z file.

If I use:

```
Dim archive = Await localFolder.GetFileAsync("5.7z")
IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(archive.Path, localFolder.Path)
```

I receive an error:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.InvalidDataException' occurred in System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: End of Central Directory record could not be found.

(I know... it is only for `.zip` files, but I thought I'd try.)

Can I work for unzip a 7z file in UWP?

Must I install a specific `.dll`? If so, which one?

I'd tried to install `SevenZipSharp` and `SevenZipExtractor` and  `SevenZipSharp.Net45` but in each case the install went wrong with error.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You could probably use LZMA SDK, but you'd have to recompile it to target Windows Store yourself: http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Comment: What are the error messages you're seeing? "An error" is useless for troubleshooting.

Comment: This is the error when i use  IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(archive.Path, localFolder.Path)

An exception of type 'System.IO.InvalidDataException' occurred in System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: End of Central Directory record could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved using SharpCompress 
p3-sharpcompress in the nuget package.